# Magento Browse and Upload button not working at backend in firefox

Tags: magento-1.7, flashplayer-debug

Image not uploaded using browse files and upload files button in  Magento ver. 1.10.1.0 for Firefox works good for chrome, i think it's flash player issue. so how to solve this issue i also upgrade flash player and my latest flash player for Firefox is "11,8,800,94". I found that many of the magento developer getting same issue.will anybody is there to help us to get permanent solution of this issue.

I am having magento Professional Edition

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes for magento 1.7.2 community version. Try to upgrade your firefox. Sometimes it may supports. I too faced this issue. In admin panel, in page of image upload initially browse files and upload buttons wil not appear.These buttons will appear after few seconds.